# Set to visible when item in a combobox is selected

Tags: wpf, binding, triggers

As the title says, I have a hidden border with some controls inside, and I would like to show it when a particular item in a combobox is selected.

I tried the following

```
<ComboBox Name="cmbRequiredRule" SelectedValuePath="Content"                                                                                                    
          SelectedValue="{Binding Path=ClientValidation.NarrativeRequiredRule}">
    <ComboBoxItem>All</ComboBoxItem>                         
    <ComboBoxItem>Matching</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>

<Border Visibility="Collapsed">
    <Border.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ClientValidation.NarrativeRequiredRule}" Value="Matching">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Resources> 
.... 
</Border>
```

and this property in the view model:

```
 public string NarrativeRequiredRule
    {
        get... 
        set... 
    }
```

but the trigger doesn't seem to be working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `Visibility=Collapsed` in your Style Setters, not as part of the Border Tag. I've had issues in the past where a DataTrigger would not apply when the value was specified as part of the Tag.

```
    <Border>
        <Border.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Test}" Value="Matching">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Border.Resources>
        ...
    </Border>
```

Comment: It was like that before I tried the binding I posted in my question. both have the same issue.

Comment: @Marcom I changed my answer. I just remembered an issue I had in the past when defining styles this way.

Answer (score 1):

Locally assigned value takes [precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx) over styles. Hence you need to have

```
<Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
```

in `Style` as @Rachel has pointed out.
Also I tried debugging the binding using a dummy converter and found that the value turned out to be `System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem: Matching` instead of `Matching`.

Hence your final style is:

```
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ClientValidation.NarrativeRequiredRule}" Value="System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem: Matching">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    </DataTrigger> 
                </Style.Triggers>                    
            </Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

could be binding issue. In your example below:

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=ClientValidation.NarrativeRequiredRule}" Value="Matching">
```

where is the ClientValidation located ?  because if the whole View's DataContext is bound to VM, you will need to include these hierarchies. Check your Output log, it should throw some errors if binding failes

Comment: i have a breakpoint on the property, and it gets to that point + I don't see any binding errors in the output.

Comment: thats' good. in your ViewModel, do u implement INotifyPropertyChanged?  because if u dont, then WPF wont know if your property has changed or not

Comment: it does, the same property is used in other bindings and works, so thats why i suspect the trigger